# How to get Quartz Trigger interval?

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler

I am using Quartz for scheduling the java tasks. How to get the interval time for a specific trigger

```
for(Trigger trigger : getAllTrigersFromSchduler()) {
    trigger.getDescription(); // for description
    // Need trigger interval time
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I stumble across this question and needed a solution as well,
after reading thru the [javadocs](https://www.quartz-scheduler.org/api/2.2.1/org/quartz/SimpleTrigger.html) here's how you can read the defined interval. 
It's important to note that there are different types of triggers, assuming you're using the *SimpleScheduleBuilder* for creating triggers you can do the following:

```
for(Trigger trigger : getAllTrigersFromSchduler()) {
    System.out.println(trigger.getDescription());   // for description
    // assuming a SimpleTrigger
    System.out.println(((SimpleTrigger)trigger).getRepeatInterval()));  // for interval in ms as long
}
```

regards